# Не получается закинуть сайт на github

Tags: github, хостинг

Итак, хотел попробовать разместить сайт в сети, использовав github в качестве хостинга, дабы получить затем ссылку на свой сайт вида username.github.io

Сделал все по инструкции **[отсюда](https://htmlacademy.ru/blog/99-github-as-hosting)**, но в итоге при переходе по ссылке моего сайта выдавало просто название этого сайта (репозитория), а не сам сайт, как будто гитхаб не видел файлов, которые лежали в репозитории

решил попробовать прикрепить сторонний домен .tk -
сперва выдало какое то предупреждение по поводу DNS, но при переходе по ссылке вида username.github.io уже перебрасывало на сторонний домен, но сайт по прежнему не открывался, подождав пару часов, решил вернуться на стандартный домен, удалив в настройках репозитория ссылку на сторонний

однако переадресация все так же осталась, затем удалил репозиторий вообще, создал еще один новый с таким же именем и теперь уже сделал все по инструкции **[отсюда](https://pages.github.com/)**, вроде бы все успешно, но вот когда захотел перейти на сайт, то опять произошла переадресация на сторонний домен привязанный ранее, поэтому пока что два вопроса:

1) как убрать эту переадресацию или она со временем пропадет сама?

2) есть ли разница каким образом размещать файлы в репозитории (обязательно ли клонировать рипозиторий используя терминал или первый способ тоже должен работать)?

Видел здесь похожие вопросы, но там в большинстве была ошибка 404, у меня как видите немного другое, поэтому прошу не отмечать пост как дубликат

еще читал, что должна стоять ветка мастера, она у меня и стоит
и еще - может ли быть это связано с тем, что когда то давно я сменил ник на гитхабе?

Comment: Переадресация — это скорее всего кэш браузера. В простом варианте, просто его закройте и откройте. В более сложном — сбросьте в настройках кэш. Если не помогает, то проверьте куда идёт пинг (в консоли ping -t site.com ) Если не на нужный ip, то правьте hosts файл, явно укажите ip для сайта. Возможно это кэш dns провайдера. Через какое-то время он обновится и правку в hosts можно будет убрать.

Comment: сделал чуток по другому - сменил браузер и страница открылась) но вот вопрос почему первым способом сайт не отображало а вторым уже отображает остается открытым. зачем вообще нужно что-то клонировать? Почему нельзя просто закинуть файлы сайта в репозиторий на хитхабе через браузер, чтобы все работало (в первом способе так и делают и все вроде должно работать, но почему то не работает)?

Comment: Вы точно инструкцию гитхаба читали? Там по-моему всё крайне просто — сделать репозиторий и связать его с локальным. Дальше как обычный git — сайт автоматом обновляется.

Comment: ага, кажется все просто пока на элементарных шагах не начинают появляться проблемы различные, о чем и свидетельствует целая куча подобных вопросов у людей. я уже понял кажется в чем была главная проблема - что у меня файл корневой назывался не index.html а site2.html

Comment: `файл назывался не index.html а site2.html`, `сменил браузер и страница открылась`. Что, простите? Как смена браузера изменила имя файла?

Comment: никак, я разве писал что смена браузера изменяла имя файла?